# Function to create new array producing undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement

I am trying to write a program that creates an array and populates it with a range of numbers. The function  range's x, y, z variables correlates to the start number, the end number, and the number value of each step. My goal is produce an array with all the numbers between (and including) x and y that is created with each step. Here is the code:

```js
let newarray = []

function range (x, y, z){
  if (x === undefined || y === undefined || z === undefined || (x > y) || (z < 0)) {
    return newarray;                          // returns empty array if x, y, or z is undefined, x is greater than y or z is a negative integer
  }
  else if (y > x) {
    for (x; x < y; x = x += z) {
      newarray.push(x);                       //pushes x into an array then adds z into x and loops until x exceeds y
    }
  } 
  else {
    return newarray;                          //prints out new array
  }
}

console.log(range(0, 10, 2));
console.log(range(10, 30, 5));
console.log(range(-5, 2, 3));
```

right now it is producing undefined for all three numbers. My research suggests something about asynchronicity? I'm not sure what that means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things are at play here:

1. `newArray` should be defined inside the function scope rather than as a global variable. Otherwise, subsequent calls to the function will keep appending onto the same array, which is likely not your intention (and if it was, there's `array.concat()` for that).
2. Your last `else` is unreachable, so the function will either return an empty array for input failing your validation or return `undefined` when control reaches the end of the function after populating the array in the `else if` block.
3. `x = x += z` is probably intended as `x += z`.
4. You should disallow `z === 0` otherwise you'll wind up with an infinite loop.
5. Normal JS style is to `camelCase` variable names.

Additionally, I find it's easier to write *positive* conditionals than *negative* conditionals. In this case, enumerating what arguments are allowed seems cleanest. This approach enables you to only have one `return` statement and fewer conditional branches, mitigating potential confusion.

Here's a version that addresses these issues:

```js
function range(x, y, z) {
  const newArray = [];
  
  if ([x, y, z].indexOf(undefined) < 0 && x < y && z > 0) {
    for (; x < y; x += z) {
      newArray.push(x);
    }
  } 
  
  return newArray;
}

console.log(range(0, 10, 2));
console.log(range(10, 30, 5));
console.log(range(-5, 2, 3));
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! The code runs as intended but the code evaluator for my school registers "newarray" in the "let newarray = []" as an unexpected token, but it runs fine so i'm not sure what to make of it.

Comment: I camel cased `newarray` to `newArray` throughout. Are you sure you copied thoroughly (no missing brackets, etc)? I'm sure `const` is allowed if `let` is. Let me know how it turns out for you.

Comment: i copied directly and added x <= y instead of x < y, the output is correct but it says const is reserved.

Comment: That's funny, I wonder what interpreter they're using. You can switch `const` to `let` or `var` and you should be fine.

Comment: Looks like the interpretor only understands var, that solved the issue!

Answer (score 1):

Note that the section where you check `else if (y > x)` does not have a return. When this condition is true, your function returns `undefined`. To fix the problem, just add `return newarray;` as the last line in the function. Then remove all other lines with `return new array;`.

Comment: You should also mention the `let newarray = []` being outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

- The `else` block is not required as it will be unreachable and will 
  return `undefined`.
- Corrected `x = x + z` from `x = x += z`.
- The array declaration was outside, so every time the old data will be
  appended with newer data from the for loop.

```js
 function range (x, y, z){

      let newarray = [];

      if (x === undefined || y === undefined || z === undefined ||  (x > y) || (z < 0)){
        return newarray;    
      }
      else if (y > x) { 
       for (x; x < y; x = x + z){
           newarray.push(x); 
        }
      }    
    return newarray;
      
    }
    console.log(range(0, 10, 2));
    console.log(range(10, 30, 5));
    console.log(range(-5, 2, 3));
```